# How to combine purchase and click data togehter in sparse matrix

Tags: machine-learning, recommender-system, sparse, calibration, scoring-rules

my problem is the following: I have purchase probability estimations of different products. The model behind don't take care of any inter-correlations through these products. So my task is to re-calibrate the probabilities and take inter-correlations into account.

To calibrate my data I have additional click data and real-purchases given. 

Overall I have 3 different matrices.

Matrix (1): Purchase probabilities (between 0 and 1) per product/per user 
Matrix (2): Real-purchases (coded as binary) per product/per user 
Matrix (3): Click data (coded as integer) per product/per user

My question is now, how can I combine the data to proof my probabilities in Matrix (1) using the additional data in Matrix (2) and (3) on the condition that my real-purchase data are based on N=1000 (1%) and my click-data are based on N=3000 (3%) users of overall N=100.000 users.

Which model I could use here? 
Are there similar examples in the filed of Recommander Systems?

Thank you for any idea!

Comment: How did you come up with matrix 1?